# How to avoid overwriting a text file?

Tags: python, file, overwrite

I use a click program the help of PyGame in Python. I want to use the program multiple times by opening up the program, and shutting it down and reopening it again.

So basically I open the program, click something, and it writes the click time into a .txt file. My problem is, when I shut down the program and run it again, it overwrites the .txt file. So my question is, how to avoid this?

```
#Pygame program....
f = open("test.txt","w") 
f.write("write something")
```

Comment: Use the file mode `'a'` (append) instead of `'w'`.

Comment: chang `f = open("test.txt", "a")` which means append mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in append mode

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: ohhhh, that easy? what does "a" mean?

Comment: it means append